# neovim takes a long time to open files

Tags: syntax-highlighting, performance, plugin-vim-polyglot

On profiling, I found that `<SNR>101_parse_screen()` is taking above 6 seconds. This problem goes away when I comment out the plugin [vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot).
This is most evident for vue files. Not sure if it's a bug, so posting this here.

Not using `vim-polyglot` is a possible solution, but it seems to work best for me, and don't want to abandon it.

any workarounds?

Will add more details if needed.

Comment: Maybe try to temporary remove `vim-polyglot`, and check with original `vue` plugin (links in README). Was this issue always present, or started after some update? Also, even if it's not a bug, it's worth asking directly on issue tracker.

Comment: Running `:verbose function <SNR>101_parse_screen()` would tell you which script that function comes from.

Comment: I agree with grodzik, this sounds like a problem with vim-polyglot. You might have more luck posting it on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot/issues).

Comment: Ironically, that plugin claims "It won't affect your startup time" in big bold letters :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a search on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=language%3A%22Vim+Script%22+parse_screen&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) and [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl:vim+%22parse_screen%22).  From the results, it's pretty reasonable to assume that that function is from [vim-css-color](https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color), which isn't in `vim-polyglot`.

In fact it looks like it was removed in 2015 for [performance reasons](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot/commit/c154d82557a4a7642510ee9a4f0c1a8efb9af7e2).  Are you sure you're using the most recent version of `vim-polyglot`?

Comment: I later realized that I was actually using vim-css-color alongside vim-polyglot! that seems to be the culprit. Thanks